# use part of string in query

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, date, zend-db

i have a mysql table with date of birth, so an example field would be:

```
dob
----
1989-01-01
```

I have pulled todays date in zend framework with the following code:

```
public function todaysDate()
    {
        $date = new Zend_Date();
        $date = $date->get(Zend_Date::MONTH_SHORT . '-' . Zend_Date::DAY_SHORT);
        return $date;
    }
```

This shows current date in format:

```
9-24
```

Now i want to search the dob field in my mysql table for anyway with the month 9 and day 24 in their dob disregarding year. how do i do this?

please note the dob is not a date field, its a text field

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE (month(dob) = 9) AND (day(dob) = 24)
```